# Setup materialDesign:PackIcon code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, button, material-design

I'm trying assign materialDesign:PackIcon code behind. Here's my code.

```
for (int i = 0; i<PrinterNumber; i++)
{
    Button btn_Restart = new Button();
    btn_Restart.Name = string.Format("PrinterRestartButtton{0}", i);
    btn_Restart.Width = 50;
    btn_Restart.Height = 25;
    btn_Restart.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
    btn_Restart.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
    btn_Restart.Content = "Restart";
    //btn_Restart.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    btn_Restart.Click += Btn_Restart_Click;
    btn_Restart.Style = (Style) Application.Current.TryFindResource("MaterialDesignRaisedDarkButton");
    Grid.SetRow(btn_Restart, i + 2);
    Grid.SetColumn(btn_Restart, 10);
    grd_WorkArea.Children.Add(btn_Restart);
}
```

How to apply **materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Restart"** to 
btn_Restart.Content property?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the `Content` property to a `PackIcon`:

```
btn_Restart.Content = new MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf.PackIcon 
    { Kind = MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf.PackIconKind.Restart };
```